# Insanely-huge time calculation for nested NMinimize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to perform a nested optimization of a function f[] with respect to 13 different parameters (a1, a2, a3, ..., a13). The function also depend by another variable, which is not an optimization variable (let name it b) and that can have two instances (b1 and b2, respectively).
I first define the inner optimization process as follows:

```
fC[a1_?NumericQ,a2_?NumericQ,a3_?NumericQ,a4_?NumericQ,a5_?NumericQ,a6_?NumericQ,a7_?NumericQ,a8_?NumericQ] := 

NMinimize[{f[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,b1]},{a9,a10,a11,a12,a13}][[1]] 

+ 

NMinimize[{f[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13, b2]},{a9,a10,a11,a12,a13}][[1]]
```

Then, I launched the outer optimization process as follows:

```
NMinimize[{fC[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8]},{a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8}]
```

Unfortunaly, this procedure will lead to extremely long optimization time, regardless the complexity of the function to be optimized f[]. Also for extremely simple function (just the multiplication of all the 13 variables) and very strict constraints, the optimization is not completed even after hours (Running...).

I am quite sure to have written the instructions correctly: indeed, if I reduce the number of unkowns to just one or two I finally get a results by the outer optimization loop.
However, the process time for all the variables is insanely slow and I am sure there is something wrong. Just to be clearer, a single instance of the inner optimization step fC[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8] using random values for the 8 unknowns takes a fraction of second. Therefore, I do not understand why the outer optimization takes an extremely huge computation time (and, in the end, it is not completed not even in hours).

I am not a big expert of the language, so I am afraid I am missing something important. Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Thank you,
Eugene

**EDIT**

As discussed above, the problem appears almost with ANY function f. The simulation time is huge even with:

```
f[a1_,a2_,a3_,a4_,a5_,a6_,a7_,a8_,a9_,a10_,a11_,a12_,a13_,b_]:= a1*a2*a3*a4*a5*a6*a7*a8*a9*a10*a11*a12*a13*b
```

Below, an example of a working code with extreme simulation time (the solution is obvious, but the optimization did not get a final result after 30 minutes):

```
f[a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, a5_, a6_, a7_, a8_, a9_, a10_, a11_, a12_, a13_,
   b_] := a1*a2*a3*a4*a5*a6*a7*a8*a9*a10*a11*a12*a13*b

fC[a1_?NumericQ, a2_?NumericQ, a3_?NumericQ, a4_?NumericQ, 
  a5_?NumericQ, a6_?NumericQ, a7_?NumericQ, a8_?NumericQ] := 
 NMinimize[{f[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, 
      1]}, {a9, a10, a11, a12, a13}][[1]] + 
  NMinimize[{f[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13,
       2]}, {a9, a10, a11, a12, a13}][[1]]

NMinimize[{fC[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8], 
  1 <= a1 <= 2 && 1 <= a2 <= 2 && 1 <= a3 <= 2 && 1 <= a4 <= 2 && 
   1 <= a5 <= 2 && 1 <= a6 <= 2 && 1 <= a7 <= 2 && 1 <= a8 <= 2}, {a1,
   a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8}]
```

If I simplify the function f to a very trivial case, I get a final result in a resonable time (30 seconds):

```
f[a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, a5_, a6_, a7_, a8_, a9_, a10_, a11_, a12_, a13_,
   b_] := a1

fC[a1_?NumericQ, a2_?NumericQ, a3_?NumericQ, a4_?NumericQ, 
  a5_?NumericQ, a6_?NumericQ, a7_?NumericQ, a8_?NumericQ] := 
 NMinimize[{f[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, 
      1]}, {a9, a10, a11, a12, a13}][[1]] + 
  NMinimize[{f[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13,
       2]}, {a9, a10, a11, a12, a13}][[1]]

NMinimize[{fC[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8], 
  1 <= a1 <= 2 && 1 <= a2 <= 2 && 1 <= a3 <= 2 && 1 <= a4 <= 2 && 
   1 <= a5 <= 2 && 1 <= a6 <= 2 && 1 <= a7 <= 2 && 1 <= a8 <= 2}, {a1,
   a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8}]
```

Comment: Can you check your code? You have unbalanced braces in you outer `NMinimize`.

Comment: Shall we guess the function f? Haven't seen any clairvoyants on this site yet.

Comment: The actual expression of f is complex; however, as mentioned in the post, the problem is with ANY function f ("regardless the complexity of the function to be optimized "). The simulation time is huge even with: f = a1*a2*a3*a4*a5*a6*a7*a8*a9*a10*a11*a12*a13*b . As discussed in the post, each istance of fc takes a fraction of seconds.
My concern is that there is something not optimized in the construction of the nested optimization loops that make the optimization time increasing significantly.
@MarcoB: thank you, this is not the original code, I tried to simplify it for making it clearer.

Comment: I added a working code above, despite the simplicity of the function it takes a lot of time (I stopped it after 10 minutes without results).

Comment: @Eugene Why do you have a mixture of `Minimize` and `NMinimize` in your definition of the trivial `fC`?

Comment: It was just a typo, just corrected. The problem is still present. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried not nesting the functions? Just `NMinimize[{f[a1..a13,1]+f[a1..a13,2],conditions},{a1..a13}]` For your first simple case I get an immediate answer with the message `NMinimize: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded`, which is what I would expect when trying to minimize the multiplication of a bunch of numbers.

Comment: Thank for the comment; however, I need to neste the optimization loops. Indeed, the parameters a9,...,a13 can change for each value of b (b1 and b2, in the example). Conversely, the parameters a1,...,a8 must be fixed for any instance of b. 
What I need is to find the optimal values of a1,....,a8 that minimize the functions fc (which is the sum of the minimal value of f[b1] + f[b2] with respect to a9,...,a13).